# AngularJS Expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a quick question on AngularJS:
I have one property from JSON as

```
"icon-class": "home"
```

Now I need to do this in my html page:

```
<span class="{{sub.icon-class}}"></span>
```

the sub is some other object here.

But inspecting the DOM, the value of the above expression is always zero (0). I guess the dash(-) is acting like a subtraction here.

How to do it I could not make it resolve.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can use bracket notation to retrieve the value when the key has non-standard characters:

```
<span class="{{sub['icon-class']}}"></span>
```

Read more about accessing properties at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: superb, thanks. It worked. I understand the logic now. array[key] seems working. Thank you so much. I am accepting and up-voting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<span class="{{sub['icon-class']}}"></span>
```

But in general I'd avoid hyphens in variable names

Comment: You have a syntax error - the dot shouldn't be there.

Comment: ya, looks like it is a syntax error. Hey, guys not its working. Thank you so much.